# Punctuation following "That said"

Tags: punctuation

Is there a standard punctuation that should follow "that said"?  For example:

> I use "that said" a lot.  **That said,** I just do what I've always done.

I have always used a comma after "that said", ignoring Microsoft dictionary's insistence that it is incorrect (I get a green underline under the comma).  A co-worker saw this recently though and said it should be a semicolon.  As in:

> I usually use a comma.  **That said;** a semicolon makes Outlook happy.

Sure enough, this removes the green underline.  But this look incorrect to me.  I would almost be happier with no punctuation at all.

Is there a standard way this should be done?

Comment: MS's Grammar check is often less accurate than what just sounds right.  It is good for spotting points to look closer, but is not gospel.  In this case, if you used the more complete "That being said," I believe it would not complain.  I think it is not actually the , vs. ; that is throwing it.

Comment: It's even in the dictionary. With a comma: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/that-said?q=that+said

Answer (score 5, accepted):

['That said'](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/that-said) means 'even so' and introduces a concessive statement. It should be followed by a comma, not a full stop or semicolon. Please ignore the Microsoft grammar algorithm.